# Traveling Salesman Heuristic

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list, traveling-salesman

My current idea is:
Start with point 0 and connect it with it's nearest point. For all the remaining nodes, insert it into all possible locations and keep the configuration that has the least cost.

So I start with point 0. The node closest to point 0 is point 1.

So I now have 0->1 -> 0

For point 2 (and all the remaining nodes) I will check all possibilities on where the new node could be:

**2** -> 0 -> 1 -> 2

0 -> **2** -> 1 -> 0

0 -> 1-> **2** -> 0

From here I find that

0 -> 1 - > 2 -> 0 has the least total euclidean distance, so that is the configuration I will keep.

I will keep using this logic for the rest of my nodes.

Is there an easy way to implement this in c++? My current thought is maybe linked list would be a good idea but I'd like to be able to use vectors if possible. Does anyone have any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: Not at my PC to experiment with a full answer, but you probably want `std::reduce` (C++17) or `std::accumulate` using a function which calculates the distance between points as the '`BinaryOperator`'. Use `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` to store your path.

Comment: Thanks I'll experiment around Jack

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a directed graph and then implementing dijkstra's algorithm. In a directed graph dijkstra's algorithm will give you the shortest path from a starting node to all other nodes in the graph and not just the few nodes that you want.